# Can I update my Android app to support 64 bit after August 1st?

Tags: android, google-play, react-native

I understand the requirement to update to 64 bit by Aug 1st, and the 2021 deadline and all that.

I wont be able to update my app to support 64 before Aug 1. If instead I updated it the next day or whenever (and that update did support 64). Would it be declined? Or does it mean, ONLY 32 bit supported apps will not be able to be updated going forward?

I have read the Announcement from Google, but this detail is unclear to me.

Thanks

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/23637991) your question and clarify what you mean by "new build" and how is that different than "update to app". Otherwise see: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/01/get-your-apps-ready-for-64-bit.html

Comment: I think my question is clear. I wont be able to update my app to support 64 before Aug 1. If instead I updated it the next day (and that update did support 64). Would it be declined? Or does it mean, ONLY 32 bit supported apps will not be able to be updated going forward

Comment: @MorrisonChang edited my question. hope it clarifies things

Comment: Given that Google is mandating 64-bit why would they decline a 64-bit update to an app in the Play store? Google will not be accepting any more NEW 32-bit apps, and will stop serving 32-bit only apps in 2021.

Comment: Okay thanks, thats all the clarification I needed. Thank you @MorrisonChang

Answer (score 0):

What Google says is that since august 1st only 64-bit compatible apk files would be accepted as updates for pre-existent 32-bit apps. After that day, your app will not be available to install for devices with 64-bit capabilities but will still be available for 32-bit devices.
Also this restriction seems to be only for apps running Android 9 Pie (API level 28) since previous versions surely are on 32-bit devices